# Can a flex app (or a portion of a flex app) be made transparent to mouse clicks?

Tags: apache-flex

I need to superimpose my Flex app above a plain HTML control on a web page, and be able to click through the Flex app to interact with the HTML control. Is there any way to do this? No permutation of `mouseEnabled="false"` or `mouseChildren="false"` seems to have the desired effect.

Context: trying to integrate Google Earth API (JavaScript/HTML) with my flex app. I am leaving a portion of the flex app transparent and empty, and positioning the Google Earth widget just below that point in the z-index. Google Earth has to be behind flex, because there are some Flex controls periodically displayed in that space.

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure there is no direct way for you to get mouse events to go through a Flash app.

You may be able to accomplish this with a combination of Javascript. Flash can call Javascript on your page, so you can create a function that passes clicks detected by Flash to the function and it will send the event to the page below it. I'm not 100% this will work but it's worth a try (You might have some trouble getting the correct coordinates).

Comment: That's what I was afraid of. I'll be giving this method a shot this afternoon. Will update the question with any success/failure that brings me. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered embedding Google Earth into the Flex app?
Some example [here](http://www.cynergysystems.com/blogs/page/andrewtrice?entry=google_eath_flex_source_code)

Comment: That's not actual embedding -- embedding can't be done at this point. Your example is actually positioning the Google Earth widget in a `<div>` above the Flex app on the page, something that won't work for me since I need to show some Flex controls above Google Earth.